# Calico node remains not ready when a new node with a 192.168.178.x IP joins a K8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, fedora, calico

```
kube-system   pod/calico-node-9czgm                                  0/1     Running     3          42d
kube-system   pod/calico-node-msfjk                                  0/1     Running     0          5m37s
```

...is what I get when a let "moon" to join the cluster as outlined below...

```
NAMESPACE   NAME        STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION
            node/moon   Ready    <none>                 5m38s   v1.20.5
            node/sky    Ready    control-plane,master   276d    v1.21.2
```

Whereby `pod/calico-node-9czgm` is sky's calico node that is running just fine (1/1 Ready) before `moon` joins and after moon is deleted from the k8s cluster.

> ❯ kubectl logs pod/calico-node-msfjk  -n kube-system -f Error from
> server: Get
> "https://192.168.178.23:10250/containerLogs/kube-system/calico-node-msfjk/calico-node?follow=true":
> dial tcp 192.168.178.23:10250: i/o timeout

`pod/calico-node-9czgm` tells me:

```
2021-07-04 20:39:38.999 [INFO][72] felix/ipsets.go 760: Doing full IP set rewrite family="inet" numMembersInPendingReplace=2 setID="all-hosts-net"
bird: Reconfiguration requested by SIGHUP
bird: Reconfiguring
bird: device1: Reconfigured
bird: direct1: Reconfigured
bird: Reconfigured
2021-07-04 20:39:39.023 [INFO][76] confd/resource.go 277: Target config /etc/calico/confd/config/bird.cfg has been updated due to change in key: /calico/bgp/v1/host
2021-07-04 20:39:43.185 [INFO][76] confd/client.go 897: Recompute BGP peerings: HostBGPConfig(node=moon; name=ip_addr_v4) updated; HostBGPConfig(node=moon; name=network_v4) updated
bird: Reconfiguration requested by SIGHUP
bird: Reconfiguring
bird: device1: Reconfigured
bird: direct1: Reconfigured
bird: Adding protocol Mesh_192_168_178_23
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_23: Initializing
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_23: Starting
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_23: State changed to start
bird: Reconfigured
2021-07-04 20:39:43.198 [INFO][76] confd/resource.go 277: Target config /etc/calico/confd/config/bird.cfg has been updated due to change in key: /calico/bgp/v1/host
2021-07-04 20:39:53.134 [INFO][72] felix/summary.go 100: Summarising 13 dataplane reconciliation loops over 1m1.6s: avg=14ms longest=77ms ()
2021-07-04 20:40:11.444 [INFO][74] monitor-addresses/startup.go 774: Using autodetected IPv4 address on interface eth0: 88.99.99.99/32
```

The IP 192.168.178.23 belongs to my notebook's WiFi interface. So apparently I need to override the local' interface IP with my public IP which I try to do via `--node-ip=93.93.17.11` in `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/kubeadm.conf` but everything remains broken and the kubelet additionally reports:

> Jul 04 22:58:43 moon kubelet[92613]: E0704 22:58:43.610441   92613
> kubelet_node_status.go:586] Failed to set some node status fields:
> failed to validate nodeIP: node IP: "93.93.17.11" not found in the
> host's network interfaces

I am using K8s v1.20.5 with cri-o v1.20 on Fedora 34.

Comment: If possible, please include your Calico deployment yaml files. Calico [docs](https://docs.projectcalico.org/reference/resources/node) state that "When starting a `calico/node instance`, the name supplied to the instance should match the name configured in the Node resource. By default, starting a `calico/node` instance will automatically create a node resource using the `hostname` of the compute host."
If you created nodes without explicitly stating resource names, this may by an issue.

Comment: My Calico deployment is `kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.19/manifests/calico.yaml` but thanks this is a point I can pursue further. cc @PawełGrondal

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: Are you able ping beetween 2 VMs? Is there any firewall?